# Get Request Host Name Without Port in Flask

Tags: python, flask, request, port, hostname

I've just managed to get my app server hostname in Flask using `request.host` and `request.url_root`, but both field return the request hostname with its port.

I want to use field/method that returns only the request hostname without having to do string replace, if any.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no Werkzeug (the WSGI toolkit Flask uses) method that returns the hostname alone.
What you can do is use Python's urlparse module to get the hostname from the result Werkzeug gives you:

python 3

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

o = urlparse(request.base_url)
print(o.hostname)
```

python 2

```
from urlparse import urlparse
    
o = urlparse("http://127.0.0.1:5000/")
print(o.hostname)  # will display '127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: This doesn't get the hostname, is just shows how to remove the port number from the hostname once you have the hostname

Comment: @duhaime the question said "both field return hostname with its port", so I answered the posted question. If you need something different you should look for the appropriate question or ask it yourself..

Answer (score 14):

Building on Juan E's Answer, this was my

**Solution for Python3:**

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
o = urlparse(request.base_url)
host = o.hostname
```

Answer (score 10):

This is working for me in python-flask application.

```
from flask import Flask, request
print "Base url without port",request.remote_addr
print "Base url with port",request.host_url
```

Comment: Thats not the server host, thats the user host

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it on flask template (jinja2):

```
<!--Without port -->
{{ request.remote_addr }}

<!-- With port -->
{{ request.hostname }}
```

Comment: remote_addr is client's address, not server's.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, wekzeug.urls.url_parse() does provide a "host" property, though it is not displayed in the **str**() of the object:

```
>>> from werkzeug.urls import url_parse
>>> url_parse('https://auth.dev.xevo-dev.com:443/path/to/me?query1=x&query2')
URL(scheme='https', netloc='auth.dev.xevo-dev.com:443', path='/path/to/me', query='query1=x&query2', fragment='')
>>> url_parse('https://auth.dev.xevo-dev.com:443/path/to/me?query1=x&query2').host
'auth.dev.xevo-dev.com'
>>>
```