# Get the host scheme and domain using Flask

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I have a certain use case where a Flask app is **not** configured with SERVER_NAME and it resides in a subpath (say, http://example.com/subpath/subpath2), and, from within a request context, I need to extract just the http://example.com.

I noticed that, without SERVER_NAME being set in the Flask config, `url_for` with `_external=True` is still able to retrieve the full URL including the domain on which the Flask app is being served. So I figured there must be a way that Flask (or Werkzeug) retrieves the domain. I dug around inside the `url_for` function and what resulted was this function which I made to get the domain from within a request context.

```
from flask.globals import _request_ctx_stack

def get_domain():
    fragments = [
        _request_ctx_stack.top.url_adapter.url_scheme,
        _request_ctx_stack.top.url_adapter.get_host(''),
    ]
    return '://'.join(fragments)
```

I realise I'm accessing private members, but there is no other obvious way to do it that I could find.
Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna know the host domain name (example.com, by example) I recommend you to check this other StackOverflow question: [Get Request Host Name Without Port in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889441/get-request-host-name-without-port-in-flask)

It uses `urllib.parse` to parse the full requested URL and get the host name.

If the answer seems unclear, there is my Minimal Reproductible Code (from the same question, but edited) for Python3:

```py
import flask, urllib.parse
app = flask.Flask('MyWebApp')
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Host domain name is: " + str(urllib.parse.urlparse(flask.request.base_url).hostname)
app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=80)
```

If you need to get `http://example.com` instead of `example.com`, just add it with a code like that `hostname = "http://" + hostname`.